# Python: __slots__ and its usage of descriptors

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython, python-3.2, slots

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('a',)

class Bar(Foo):
    @property
    def a(self):
        return super(Bar, self).a

 super(Bar, Bar()).a = 4
```

If I'm using this code, this doesn't work:

```
>>> super(Bar, Bar()).a = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Why?

According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#__slots__), `__slots__` are implemented :

> `__slots__` are implemented at the class level by creating descriptors (Implementing Descriptors) for each variable name. As a result, class
>   attributes cannot be used to set default values for instance variables
>   defined by `__slots__`; otherwise, the class attribute would overwrite
>   the descriptor assignment.

But descriptors can cope with inheritance (at least if written in pure python).

Does anyone get know, why this is not working with `__slots__`?

**Edit**: It seems like descriptors are generally not working with `super()`, if you're trying to write (read works, though). So my question would rather be: Why are descriptors read-only, if invoked with `super()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super()` doesn't return the descriptor, it returns the *result* of *getting* the descriptor. It doesn't return functions either, it returns the bound method; functions act as descriptors too, and their `.__get__()` method returns a method.

Because there is no `a` defined on the *instance*, there is no value and the descriptor `.__get__()` raises an AttributeError.

Things work if you define `a` on instances of `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('a',)
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'spam'
```

So, accessing a `__slots__` descriptor without a value raises an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('a',)
... 
>>> Foo.a
<member 'a' of 'Foo' objects>
>>> Foo().a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: a
>>> Foo.a.__get__(Foo(), Foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: a
```

but give the instance a value, and the `AttributeError` goes away:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('a',)
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 'spam'
... 
>>> Foo.a.__get__(Foo(), Foo)
'spam'
```

Now `super()` can find the result of the descriptor just fine (demonstrating with a different attribute name to not clobber `self.a`):

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     __slots__ = ('b',)
...     @property
...     def b(self):
...         return super(Bar, self).a
... 
>>> Bar().a
'spam'
```

Comment: Yes. I just figured it out, too. It's really because `super` is special.

Comment: @DavidHalter: Not really; it's because the descriptor raises `AttributeError` when the attribute is missing from the instance.